# How to make sure the key's order can not be changed when traversing a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

For example,I input 3 Strings:Hagzou Hugzou Jigxng as the keys of a HashMap,

but when I traversing the HashMap by key,the order has been changed:Hugzou Hagzou Jigxng.

Is that possible to make sure the order can not be changed when output the keys?

like this:

input:  Hagzou Hugzou Jigxng ###

output: Hagzou Hugzou Jigxng

thx a lot!

Here is my code:

```
    HashMap< String, Integer > distance = new HashMap< String, Integer >(); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
    while (true) {
        String city = input.next();
        if (city.equals("###"))
            break;
        distance.put(city, null);
    }
    for (String city : distance.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(city);
    }
```

Comment: use a [LinkedHashMasp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LinkedHashMap`:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key
>   is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if
>   m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true
>   immediately prior to the invocation.)

In other words - while `LinkedHashMap` has a way to access entries by their hash code, like the regular `HashMap` it also maintains a doubly-linked list and maintain the order of the items insertion. This way when you use its iterator, you'll get the items at the same order you inserted them.